# puppet copy directory but not its content

Tags: recursion, copy, puppet

I want to manage files `/home/user_name/scripts/file0`, `/home/user_name/scripts/file1`, ... on my nodes, as copies of files with the same paths on the master.

Relying on `/home/user_name` to be present on every node, I put this in the manifest:

```
file { '/home/user_name/scripts':
  ensure  => 'directory',
  path    => '/home/user_name/scripts',
  recurse => true
}
```

That indeed gets the directory created on each of the nodes, but the contents `file0`, `file1`, ... are not copied.

I tried to add a `source` parameter, and also `recurse=>remote`, but with no further success.

**Update**: Trying to add the `source` parameter, I added:

```
file { '/home/user_name/scripts':
  ensure  => 'directory',
  path    => '/home/user_name/scripts',
  recurse => true,
  source  => '/home/user_name/scripts'
}
```

But with no success. Btw, here's the output when running `puppet apply`

> ```
> Notice: Compiled catalog for puppet, master_dns in environment production in 0.64 seconds
> Notice: /Stage[main]/Exec_script/Exec[add_archi]/returns: executed successfully
> Notice: Applied catalog in 2.60 seconds
> ```

Comment: Can we see the actual resource with the `source` attribute you claim that you added as well as the relevant output from the agent during catalog application.

Comment: @MattSchuchard I have just edited my post

Comment: That `source` attribute looks suspicious. Try looking at this: https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.2/types/file.html#file-attribute-source. Also, that agent output has no `file` in it.

Comment: sorry @MattSchuchard the doc is not clear. How the `source` attribute should look like ? I want to avoid `puppet://` because I could be in a situation to sync local folders on my master to the agents

Comment: @user2478159, where do you mean to copy the files *from*?  This determines what form the value of the `source` attribute should take.  It is also covered in the docs Matt linked, so what part of those is unclear to you?

Comment: @JohnBollinger the files I want to copy are located in my master node, the path, precisely here's the folder path  `/home/user_name/scripts`. So I want this to be copied recursively on the agent nodes. But, when applying the manifest, I only got a copy of the `scripts` folder on each agent node, but not the content inside the `scripts` folder. So, I tried then to add a `source` attribute the way I posted in my question, but @MattSchuchard seems to indicate it is not correctly formatted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@MattSchuchard already pointed you to [the relevant documentation](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.3/types/file.html#file-attribute-source).  They explain that Puppet supports four alternatives for the form of the `source` parameter, and that the form you're trying to use relies on *local* files as the source of the files being managed.  That is, local to the node being configured.

If you want to use files residing on the master as the source, and they are not directly accessible to clients (e.g. via a network file system), then you have only two alternatives left: a URI using either the `puppet:` or the `http:` scheme.  Unless you want to run an HTTP server on your master, only a `puppet:` URI is really a viable option.

By default, however, Puppet's file server serves files only out of modules, not from arbitrary paths.  And why would you *want* to serve arbitrary files from the master's file system?  What a recipe for disaster.  And why would general users need home directories on the master anyway?

The best solution would be to put the directory tree in whatever module your `file` resource appears in -- say at mymodule/files/user_name/scripts.  Then you could write your resource like so:

```
file { '/home/user_name/scripts':
  ensure  => 'directory',
  recurse => true,
  source  => 'puppet://modules/mymodule/user_name/scripts'
}
```

---

But if you insist, you should be able to leave the source files where they are now, and patch it together with a symlink:

```
mymodule/files/user_name-scripts -> /home/user_name/scripts
```

... and ...

```
file { '/home/user_name/scripts':
  ensure  => 'directory',
  recurse => true,
  source  => 'puppet://modules/mymodule/user_name-scripts',
  links   => 'follow'
}
```

Comment: thank you for the response ! I already implemented the `puppet` URI but I didn't used a symlink ;) now I know that there is no way to do this by design

Answer (score 1):

If you want Puppet to copy the files, you need to tell it where the files should be copied **from**, *i.e.* provide the **source** attribute:

```
file {'/my/path':
    ensure  => 'directory',
    path    => '/my/path',
    recurse => true,
    source  => '/home/user_name/scripts',
    }
```

This will create a directory */my/path* and recursively copy all files and directories from the node's local directory */home/user_name/scripts* to */my/path*.